# Symfony2 Process::start() fails when running in production environment

Tags: php, symfony, exec, command-line-interface

I am using the Symfony2 Process component to fire off a cli script that generates a rather large report. At which point I am using ajax to monitor it's progress and show a progress bar fill on the front end. When executing the following code in app_dev.php it runs perfectly and there are no issues. However, when I run it in production it fails to start the Process().

Here is my code:

```
public function generateAction($reportSlug)
    {
        $this->wrangler->addMoodleGlobal('CFG');
        $time = time();

        $commandSlug = "report:{$reportSlug}";
        $console = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() ."/console";

        $process = new Process("exec php {$console} {$commandSlug} {$time} > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

        $process->start();

        return $this->renderJson(json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "php {$console} {$commandSlug}",
            'time' => $time
        )));
    }
```

I have run `php app/console cache:clear --env="prod"`

as well as `php app/console cache:warmup --env="prod"`

bot to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a shared hosting service ? Sometimes the shared hosting service don't allow to execute some process, I had this issue with hostinger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the real issue was however when I changed the line

```
$process = new Process("exec php {$console} {$commandSlug} {$time} > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

to use a temp output file:

```
$process = new Process("exec php {$console} {$commandSlug} {$time} > /tmp/output.log 2>/tmp/output.log &");
```

everything started to work properly. Can anyone shed some light on this?